# How to get compatible Mule dependencies

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

When a Mule project is created by the Anypoint Studio itself, the IDE will generate the maven pom file with all compatible dependencies. But I want to get MuleSoft dependencies (Ex: Connectors, Munit module dependencies, etc)  and their compatible versions which suit the Runtime Environment from Outside or manually - not through the IDE. For example, if a new RunTime version '4.5' is released in the future, I want to know all the compatible and new dependency versions which go hand in hand with the Runtime 4.5. This should not through the IDE. Better to have a repository or any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In Studio 7.x (compatible with Mule 4.x) it tries to select versions of connectors that are are more o less up to date with that release, but it is always recommended to use the last version of each connector that is compatible with the Mule Runtime version used. For that you can look to the [release notes](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/connector/anypoint-connector-release-notes#mule_4) page to find the compatibility of each connector released by MuleSoft. Each version release usually mentions what is the minimum compatible Mule version.

Also Studio 7 has a button in the toolbar to detect updated connectors and modules and gives the option to update them.

Just to be clear, Mule 4.x doesn't have any dependencies in the pom of a Mule 4 application project. The dependencies there are needed by your application, not by the Mule Runtime.